# Problems installing NXT-ROS on Raspberry Pi

Tags: ros, nxt, raspberrypi, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am currently working on a project where I need to control a small robot with an android app via bluetooth. Since the app will later be developed for a bigger robot that uses an ROS running controllor (one that I can not get my hands on) it was recommended that I use ROS. I am trying to setup ROS on a raspberry pi and control a small Lego NXT robot with the app. The NXT wiki suggests installing ROS Electric, but the electric package for Debian seems to be unavailable(or at least it has been moved). Is there anyone who has a suggestion on what to do, and is maybe doing something similar and can give me pointers to how they managed to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/102706/problems-installing-nxt-ros-on-raspberry-pi/) by [bjarkijoha](https://answers.ros.org/users/8966/bjarkijoha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-11-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you try the answer presented [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/67831/is-there-a-newer-nxt_ros-stack-using-nxt-python-222-instead-of-120-on-raspberry-pi/)? They are using Groovy.

There is also a related discussion [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/52836/lego-nxt-ros-working-on-groovy-galapagos/).

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2013-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0